# Joining 101 columns from a dictionary of dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dictionary, machine-learning

For the love of God! I have 101 single column features and I just want to join, or merge, or concatenate them so they all have the index of the first frame. I have all the frames in a dict already! I thought that would be the hard part. 
Below I've done manually what I'd like to do. What I'd like to do is loop through the dict and get all 101 columns.

```
a=ddict['/Users/cb/Dropbox/Python Projects/Machine Learning/Data Series/Full Individual Stock Data/byd/1byd.xls']
b=ddict['/Users/cb/Dropbox/Python Projects/Machine Learning/Data Series/Full Individual Stock Data/byd/2byd.xls']
c=ddict['/Users/cb/Dropbox/Python Projects/Machine Learning/Data Series/Full Individual Stock Data/byd/3byd.xls']

d=a.join(b['Value'],lsuffix='_caller')
f=d.join(c['Value'],lsuffix='_caller')
f
```

Comment: Have you try to load your data into a DataFrame and use pd.DataFrame.merge()?

Comment: yes. I've tried merge, join, and concatenate. Clearly, I did it wrong. I am struggling to find the exact options that work with a for loop on the dict.

Comment: Let me clarify, you have 3 df in a dictionnary, each df has the same structure, and each one has a unique key in your dictionnary, correct?

Comment: Each has a unique key (it is in fact the path) and each has the same index 0-5000 or thereabouts. And two columns Date and Value. Except there are 101 dataframes in the dict.

Comment: <code>df=pd.DataFrame()
for key,value in ddict.items():
    df.join(value,lsuffix='_caller')<code>

Comment: How did you create the dictionary in the first place? The usual way to do this would be to store them in a list and then concatenate along `axis=1`. Since you made the dictionary, you should be able to make the list, or just iterate through the dict values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to

1. Create a `first` variable and set it to `True`. The first time we iterate through ou `dict()` we don't have anything to merge our dataframe with, so we will just assign the `value` to a variable
2. set the `first` variable to `False` so next time we will just merge our dataframe together
3. `df.merge()` and set `left_index` and `right_index` parameter to `True` so that our join happens on these index.

Below is a sample code.

**Input**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,2,3,4]})
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col2': [11,12,13,14]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col3': [111,112,113,114]})

d = {'df':df, 'df1':df1, 'df2':df2}


first = True
for key, value in d.items():
    if first:
        n = value
        first = False
    else:
        n = n.merge(value, left_index=True, right_index=True)

n.head()
```

**output**

```
   col1  col2  col3
0     1    11   111
1     2    12   112
2     3    13   113
3     4    14   114
```

Here is a link to `merge()` for more information [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

Comment: Sounds like a plan. Let me give it a go! I'll be back.

Comment: So the problem here is I'm only getting two columns. This also happens when I run your code.

Comment: Oh wait. It did do something correct. It just added things row wise instead of column wise.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add that, if you want to keep the keys of the dictionary as the column headers of the final dataframe you just need to add this in the end:

n.columns=d.keys()